# How to calculate median of variables?

Tags: matlab, median

suppose i have few variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` have some numerical values. How can I calculate their median in MATLAB?

```
x= median(a,b,c,d); is not working.
```

Note: `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are variables defined by a few equations and have numerical values.

Comment: [median](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/median.html) - looks like you forgot to use [] inside your () brackets

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [basics](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`median`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/median.html) is expecting a vector:

```
x= median([a,b,c,d]);
```